# Do java modules in practice offer different compile and runtime restrictions?

Tags: java, spring-boot, war, java-module

When we distribute our apps, it's very often as a spring-boot fat-jar or war. None of these technologies supports running using module-path

Some people [even say that](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-modularity#comment-12537) java modules are

> not really meant to replace WAR files (or any other “executable” style jar

but every library out there will eventually end up in some app.

So: modules can be used to introduce encapsulation / modularization at development and test time but the runtime will be different?

Comment: Not really clear over what "restrictions" are you referring here, could you share an example about it?

Comment: access / visibility restrictions

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you build and run your application.

If you build your application as a spring-boot fat jar (e.g. using the spring-boot-maven-plugin), you won't have "real" modules as runtime. Your modules will become part of the unnamed module which "requires" all other modules and "exports" all of it's packages.

You can build and run your application modular but not by creating a fat jar using the spring-boot-maven-plugin.
One way to do that is to put all dependencies in one directory, including the module with your main class and run your application like this:

```
java --module-path={MODULE-DIR-PATH} --module example.module/com.example.MainClass
```

I have created an example of an Application combining the JPMS and Spring-Boot. You can check it out here:
https://github.com/qutax/jpms-spring-example